# How do I add a texture for procedural materials as seen in this video?

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural, shader-nodes

So I am watching a procedural material tutorial video on Youtube. In the beginning, the creator has a tile-like texture in the background of his object, which is the plane. When he adds the Magic Texture and Displacement node, the image is placed and duplicated onto the plane. I am not understanding how this is working. In other words, how do I add a texture in this case so that when I do the nodes, it places itself and duplicates onto the plane as shown in the video. So far, I have added the Magic Texture and Displacement node as shown in the video and my plane is blank. Nothing changed after adding the first two nodes as it did for the creator in the video.

Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muvIS5_sXQo

and here's my file.. there's really not much done to this file but: [image]

and a screenshot of my nodes:[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: ..You can take a screen-grab of your node setup, and edit it into your question. It's very hard to guess what might be going wrong, with no evidence at all.

Comment: blend file and screenshot has been added.

Comment: You can't get the same result if you don't follow the instructions, maybe he missed some explanation but for example you need to be in Cycles, you need to subdivide your mesh, you need to be in Rendered preview, you need to go into the Material panel > Settings > Surface > Displacement > choose Displacement Only, etc